# Refer to classpath within .properties file

Tags: java, properties, classpath

Say my classpath is set to `C:/long/obscure/path/name`, and within `name` are two directories, `foo` and `bar`. I want to pass the location of `foo` and `bar` from a .properties file without including the whole path name.

My idea was to try referencing the class path with

```
fooPath = /foo
```

or

```
barPath = %CLASSPATH%/bar
```

but these do not work.

Is it possible to refer to the classpath within the properties file without explicitly defining it therein?

Comment: I think `Class#getResource` should be able to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

If you have c:/long/obscure/path/name in the classpath, you only have to refer to /foo

If you want the full classpath:

1. Get /foo from your properties file
2. Get the classpath from the system:

   String classPath = prop.getProperty("java.class.path", null);
3. joint the two strings

Comment: Certainly a valid solution, but I'm still curious as to whether or not referencing the classpath from within properties is possible.